# k closest points to the origin

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of points: `[(x, y), (x, y), (x ,y) ... (x, y)]`.
I want the `k` nearest points to `(0, 0)`.

I'm trying to implement something like in [this](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=15974664) link. However, I am implementing the algorithm incorrectly, and I'm not sure where it's going wrong. I think perhaps `heapify` doesn't know how to maintain order between points. How can I solve this?

#### code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint
from heapq import heappush, heappop, heapify
from math import sqrt

def distance(pointA, pointB):
    return sqrt((pointB[0] - pointA[0]) ** 2 + (pointB[1] - pointA[1]) ** 2)

def closest(points, k, origin):
    heap = []
    for point in points[:k]:
        heappush(heap, point)

    for point in points[k:]:
        if distance(point, origin) < distance(heap[0], origin):
            heappop(heap)
            heappush(heap, point)
    return heap

def naive(points, k, origin):
    sortedPoints = sorted(points, key=lambda p: distance(p, origin))
    return sortedPoints[:k]

points = [(randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)) for i in range(100)]
k = 4
resA = closest(points, k, (0, 0))
resB = naive(points, k, (0, 0))
plt.scatter(*zip(*points))
plt.scatter(*zip(*resA))
plt.scatter(*zip(*resB))
plt.show()
```

#### result

The points in green are given by the naive method, and the points in orange are given by the method using a heap.

[image]

Comment: You are not maintaining the heap invariant with respect to distance.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what you mean. I thought using `heappop` and `heappush` maintained the invariant? (in the updated question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heap invariant in your solution uses the first element of the point. You want to use the distance of the point from the origin:

```
def closest(points, k, origin):

    heap = [(-distance(p, origin), p) for p in points[:k]]
    heapify(heap)

    for p in points[k:]:
        d = distance(p, origin)
        heappushpop(heap, (-d, p))
    return [p for nd, p in heap]
```

**Note**: I've also imported [`heappushpop`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappushpop) from `heapq` since it's more efficient than separate calls.

[image]

**Edit:** Removed the conditional surround the call to `heappushpop` since the conditional also exists inside that function.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Why do you use `-distance` here?

Comment: Python heaps are min heaps but you want a max heap. Easiest way to get that is to negate the key.

Comment: Why do you compare before the heappushpop? You can skip the if part and always do heappushpop with the same result.

Comment: @Panayotis it's possible that `heappushpop` does that check already. If it doesn't you might be doing O(n logk) operations unnecessarily.

Comment: @Panayotis turns out it [does do that check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L161). In that case the conditional makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using heapq, you might as well use the [`nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) function instead of reinventing it:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
result = nsmallest(k, points, lambda p : distance(p, (0, 0)))
```

Comment: From the docs, the `nsmallest` is equivalent to `sorted(iterable, key=key)[:n]`, which to me seems similar to the the naive approach (which I'm hoping to avoid). I'm prepping for interviews, and not sure if they would accept just using `nsmallest`.